# Issues with update_field in ACF for checkboxes and true/false fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field with checkboxes with 5 checkboxes filled in.

I do have a form that creates a post in my custom post type that will update all the ACF field in that post from what is filled in the form.
Right now everything works except for the checkboxes.
I have 5 checkboxes that I need to fill in.
Right now my code is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['sToOrder'])) {
    if(in_array('external', $_POST['sToOrder'])) {
        update_field('field_630c9c8100089', 'External', $postID);
    }
    if(in_array('graphical', $_POST['sToOrder'])) {
        update_field('field_630c9c8100089', 'Graphical', $postID);
    }
    if(in_array('Web', $_POST['sToOrder'])) {
        update_field('field_630c9c8100089', 'Web', $postID);
    }
    if(in_array('tracking', $_POST['sToOrder'])) {
        update_field('field_630c9c8100089', 'Tracking', $postID);
    }
    if(in_array('SEO', $_POST['sToOrder'])) {
        update_field('field_630c9c8100089', 'SEO', $postID);
    }
}
```

From my var dumps, this code gets the values of all the checkboxes if they are checked.

But the ACF field will ONLY check the last checkbox that is checked.
If I have checked for “Graphical, Tracking and SEO” it will only check the SEO checkbox in my post.
Any idea how I can make this update so that it checks the checkboxes in back-end that is checked in the form?

***Edit***
This is the complete ACF checkbox field that I have with 5 checkboxes in back-end Wordpress copied from dev window so not good formatted:

```
<div class="acf-field acf-field-checkbox acf-field-630c9c8100089" data-name="ordered" data-type="checkbox" data-key="field_630c9c8100089">
<div class="acf-label">
<label for="acf-field_630c9c8100089">Channels Ordered</label></div>
<div class="acf-input">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089]"><ul class="acf-checkbox-list acf-bl">
<li><label class="selected"><input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9c8100089-external" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089][]" value="External" checked="checked"> External</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9c8100089-graphical" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089][]" value="Graphical"> Graphical</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9c8100089-Web" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089][]" value="Web"> Web</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9c8100089-Tracking" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089][]" value="Tracking"> Tracking</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9c8100089-SEO" name="acf[field_630c9c8100089][]" value="SEO"> SEO</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Problems with True/False fields:**

Another problem I see that I have is a true/false field.
This is my true/false field in back-end:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9cc60008a-field_630c9fcb225c0" name="acf[field_630c9cc60008a][field_630c9fcb225c0]" value="1" class="" autocomplete="off">
```

What name should I use here when I see 2 acf field values in name.
This does not seem to work:

```
update_field('field_630c9cc60008a', 1, $postID);
update_field('field_630c9cc60008a', "1", $postID);
update_field('field_630c9cc60008a', true, $postID);
```

But nothing works. It will not change at all.

Anyone that can give me any pointers on where I am doing this wrong and what I can do to make it work?

Comment: ````$_POST['sToOrder']```` is an array...? Are you sure...? I say that because you search in an array with ````in_array()```` function.  Even without seeing the HTML code of your form, this recovery via PHP seems strange to me.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="<?php echo $stOrd;?>" name="sToOrder[]" value="<?php echo $stOrd_val; ?>">` This is the checkboxes that is in a loop. 
I can always but then on different namings, but the problem is still the same. the Update_field only updates the last entry of the checkboxes.
The output of the code is correct. It returns all the correct checkboxes.

Comment: From what I know each checkbox should have its own name. And you will have all these names present in the super variable $_POST. And if you have this code on the source page ````<input type="checkbox" id="acf-field_630c9cc60008a-field_630c9fcb225c0" name="acf[field_630c9cc60008a][field_630c9fcb225c0]" value="1" class="" autocomplete="off">```` then you can get the variable on the next page by this code ```$variable = $_POST["acf[field_630c9cc60008a][field_630c9fcb225c0]"]```.  Knowing that this field name is really strange but hey...

Comment: I have tried to have a unique name on each checkbox. But the problem is not there.
The problem is that the ACF field is not receiving every single field. 
If I update the field with 1 value, it works. If I update the field with 2 values, it only apply's the last update and removes the first one.
For example if I check External and Graphical, ACF only displays Graphical in back-end because it removes the External since a new update was pushed to the field.

I have updated my code with the code for the checkbox field that is in back-end of wordpress from ACF.

Comment: I just solved the checkboxes by pushing all the values to an array and then use update_field and just place the array in the value field.
Now I just need to solve the True/False field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this HTML code

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="validation.php">
<input type="checkbox"  name="myCheckBox"   id="myCheckBox" value="1">
</form>
```

On your validation.php page you can check like this :

```
if($_POST["myCheckBox"]=="1")   echo "Checkbox Checked";
else echo "Checkbox Not Checked";
```

Or like this

```
if(isset($_POST["myCheckBox"])) echo "Checkbox Checked";
else echo "Checkbox Not Checked";
```

If a case is not checked, its "value" is not passed.
And in the super variable $_POST you will have character strings and not booleans.